# JSON API get requests return only one particular field

Tags: python, json, rest

I'm confused. None of the stuff I tried from other related questions worked and I can't seem to find it by googling.

I want to filter a json api response with Python, without just sorting the datafeed I get back - that's not much good to me. I also want to explicitly select one field, rather than deleting all the other fields, because sometimes there are more fields than other times. It has to be accomplished with the structure of the request, not by modifying anything after the fact.

I use the following code to get a list of sports from the matchbook api, but how would I just show the names of those sports, filtering out the id and types?

```
r7 = s.get('https://api.matchbook.com/edge/rest/lookups/sports')

r8 = r7.json()
pprint.pprint (r8)
```

This is what I get back:

```
{'offset': 0,
 'per-page': 20,
 'sports': [{'id': 112, 'name': 'Australian Rules', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 13, 'name': 'Auto Racing', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 3, 'name': 'Baseball', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 4, 'name': 'Basketball', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 14, 'name': 'Boxing', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 110, 'name': 'Cricket', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 11, 'name': 'Current Events', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 115, 'name': 'Cycling', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 116, 'name': 'Darts', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 117, 'name': 'Gaelic Football', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 8, 'name': 'Golf', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 241798357140019,
             'name': 'Greyhound Racing',
             'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 24735152712200, 'name': 'Horse Racing', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 222109340250019,
             'name': 'Horse Racing (Ante Post)',
             'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 231138347942400,
             'name': 'Horse Racing Beta',
             'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 118, 'name': 'Hurling', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 6, 'name': 'Ice Hockey', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 126, 'name': 'MMA', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 5, 'name': 'NCAA Basketball', 'type': 'SPORT'},
            {'id': 2, 'name': 'NCAA Football', 'type': 'SPORT'}],
 'total': 28}
401
[Finished in 5.3s]
```

How would I get rid of the 'id' and 'type' fields?

This is an extract of a large set of json data:

```
    {'events': [{'allow-live-betting': True,
             'category-id': [9,
                             297063445660036,
                             410444698700010,
                             410468520880009,
                             477274740480010,
                             486941505790009],
             'id': 488243069570009,
             'in-running-flag': True,
             'markets': [{'allow-live-betting': True,
                          'back-overround': 102.04249,
                          'event-id': 488243069570009,
                          'id': 488243069830010,
                          'in-running-flag': True,
                          'lay-overround': 97.95751,
                          'live': True,
                          'market-type': 'money_line',
                          'name': 'Moneyline',
                          'runners': [{'event-id': 488243069570009,
                                       'event-participant-id': 488243069720009,
                                       'id': 488243069860009,
                                       'market-id': 488243069830010,
                                       'name': 'G Mager',
                                       'prices': [{'available-amount': 48.42639,
                                                   'currency': 'GBP',
                                                   'decimal-odds': 1.53191,
                                                   'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
                                                   'odds': 1.53191,
                                                   'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
                                                   'side': 'back'},
                                                  {'available-amount': 473.49579,
                                                   'currency': 'GBP',
                                                   'decimal-odds': 1.51546,
                                                   'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
                                                   'odds': 1.51546,
                                                   'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
                                                   'side': 'back'},
                                                  {'available-amount': 96.87754,
                                                   'currency': 'GBP',
                                                   'decimal-odds': 1.40322,
                                                   'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
                                                   'odds': 1.40322,
                                                   'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
                                                   'side': 'back'},
                                                  {'available-amount': 710.74,
                                                   'currency': 'GBP',
                                                   'decimal-odds': 1.5814,
                                                   'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
                                                   'odds': 1.5814,
                                                   'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
                                                   'side': 'lay'},
                                                  {'available-amount': 163.74192,
                                                   'currency': 'GBP',
                                                   'decimal-odds': 1.76336,
                                                   'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
                                                   'odds': 1.76336,
                                                   'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
                                                   'side': 'lay'},
                                                  {'available-amount': 151.55072,
                                                   'currency': 'GBP',
                                                   'decimal-odds': 1.9434,
                                                   'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
                                                   'odds': 1.9434,
                                                   'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
                                                   'side': 'lay'}],
                                       'status': 'open',
                                       'volume': 6955.72965},
                                      {'event-id': 488243069570009,
                                       'event-participant-id': 488243069660010,
                                       'id': 488243069890010,
                                       'market-id': 488243069830010,
                                       'name': 'A Bedene',
                                       'prices': [{'available-amount': 413.22093,
                                                   'currency': 'GBP',
                                                   'decimal-odds': 2.72,
                                                   'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
                                                   'odds': 2.72,
                                                   'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
                                                   'side': 'back'},
                                                  {'available-amount': 124.99383,
                                                   'currency': 'GBP',
                                                   'decimal-odds': 2.31,
                                                   'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
                                                   'odds': 2.31,
                                                   'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
                                                   'side': 'back'},
                                                  {'available-amount': 142.97238,
                                                   'currency': 'GBP',
                                                   'decimal-odds': 2.06,
                                                   'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
                                                   'odds': 2.06,
                                                   'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
                                                   'side': 'back'},
                                                  {'available-amount': 25.75872,
                                                   'currency': 'GBP',
                                                   'decimal-odds': 2.88,
                                                   'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
                                                   'odds': 2.88,
                                                   'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
                                                   'side': 'lay'},
                                                  {'available-amount': 244.07,
                                                   'currency': 'GBP',
                                                   'decimal-odds': 2.94,
                                                   'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
                                                   'odds': 2.94,
                                                   'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
                                                   'side': 'lay'},
                                                  {'available-amount': 39.06352,
                                                   'currency': 'GBP',
                                                   'decimal-odds': 3.48,
                                                   'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
                                                   'odds': 3.48,
                                                   'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
                                                   'side': 'lay'}],
                                       'status': 'open',
                                       'volume': 16033.12548}],
                          'start': '2017-05-15T11:05:00.000Z',
                          'status': 'open',
                          'type': 'binary',
                          'volume': 22988.85514}],
             'meta-tags': [{'id': 9,
                            'name': 'Tennis',
                            'type': 'SPORT',
                            'url-name': 'tennis'},
                           {'id': 297063445660036,
                            'name': 'R1',
                            'type': 'DATE',
                            'url-name': 'r1'},
                           {'id': 410444698700010,
                            'name': 'Italy',
                            'type': 'COUNTRY',
                            'url-name': 'italy'},
                           {'id': 410468520880009,
                            'name': 'Live Betting',
                            'type': 'OTHER',
                            'url-name': 'live-betting'},
                           {'id': 477274740480010,
                            'name': 'May 15th 2017',
                            'type': 'DATE',
                            'url-name': 'may-15th-2017'},
                           {'id': 486941505790009,
                            'name': 'ATP Rome',
                            'type': 'COMPETITION',
                            'url-name': 'ATP-Rome'}],
             'name': 'G Mager vs A Bedene',
             'sport-id': 9,
             'start': '2017-05-15T11:05:00.000Z',
             'status': 'open',
             'volume': 23098.72333},
 'offset': 0,
 'per-page': 20,
 'total': 223}
```

I want to find the event-id within this data and print "'event-id': 488243069570009"

I managed to do this with:

```
r11 = s.get('https://api.matchbook.com/edge/rest/events')

r12 = r11.json()

for each in r12['events'][0]['markets']:
    print(each['event-id'])
```

but it only prints the first event-id on the complete set of json data

Comment: `[ s['name'] for s in r8['sports'] ]`

Comment: Well, does the API permit you to make such a request? If not, you're out of luck: you can only get what the API offers, you can't make it do stuff that it's not designed to do. Which means that you need to make a request that gets the data you want with the minimum amount of "fluff" and filter out that fluff yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply create a new array using shorthand

```
data = {"offset":0,"per-page":20,"sports":[{"id":112,"name":"Australian Rules","type":"SPORT"},{"id":13,"name":"Auto Racing","type":"SPORT"},{"id":3,"name":"Baseball","type":"SPORT"},{"id":4,"name":"Basketball","type":"SPORT"},{"id":14,"name":"Boxing","type":"SPORT"},{"id":110,"name":"Cricket","type":"SPORT"},{"id":11,"name":"Current Events","type":"SPORT"},{"id":115,"name":"Cycling","type":"SPORT"},{"id":116,"name":"Darts","type":"SPORT"},{"id":117,"name":"Gaelic Football","type":"SPORT"},{"id":8,"name":"Golf","type":"SPORT"},{"id":241798357140019,"name":"Greyhound Racing","type":"SPORT"},{"id":24735152712200,"name":"Horse Racing","type":"SPORT"},{"id":222109340250019,"name":"Horse Racing (Ante Post)","type":"SPORT"},{"id":231138347942400,"name":"Horse Racing Beta","type":"SPORT"},{"id":118,"name":"Hurling","type":"SPORT"},{"id":6,"name":"Ice Hockey","type":"SPORT"},{"id":126,"name":"MMA","type":"SPORT"},{"id":5,"name":"NCAA Basketball","type":"SPORT"},{"id":2,"name":"NCAA Football","type":"SPORT"}],"total":28}
# print(data['sports'])
# for element in data['sports']: 
#     del element['id'] 
#     del element['type']
# print(data['sports'])
new_arr =  [_['name'] for _ in data['sports']];
print(new_arr)
```

**UPDATE**
Check the [online demo](https://repl.it/HSRf/3)

Comment: Yes, but that's sorting the data after I've got it back. I want to request only certain fields. As I explained, otherwise it's not much good to me.

Comment: @Davtho1983 i have added the demo. its not sorting the data as per in demo. Please check & let me know

Comment: No still no good - I want to select only the name field, not delete all the other fields. Sometimes there are more fields than other times and catching all the errors would be a pain.

Comment: Ok that's great - thanks for your patience - I'm new to both python and APIs.  One more thing - I'm having trouble applying this to stuff that's nested further inside the Json tree? What's the syntax to tell it to look in a particular place?

Comment: Say I have json beginning: {
  "id": 395729780570010,
  "name": "CSKA Moscow vs Bayer 04 Leverkusen",
  "sport-id": 15,
  "start": "2016-11-22T17:00:00.000Z",
  "in-running-flag": true,
  "allow-live-betting": true,
  "category-id": [
    15,
    394655963100010,
    395729779790010,
    395729779910010
  ],
  "status": "open",
  "volume": 0,
  "markets": [
    {
      "event-id": 395729780570010,
      "id": 395729860260010,
      "name": "Match Odds",
      "runners": [
        {

Comment: how do I isolate the event-id?

Comment: @Davtho1983 can you paste the complete json & show the expected output?

Comment: Ok I've added an extract - the whole thing is much too large

Answer (score 2):

[You can't do what you're asking the way you're asking](https://developers.matchbook.com/v1.0/reference#get-sports). The matchbook API just doesn't work like that.

You could do something silly, like add a proxy server in between you and their API that does the filtering for you, so *you* aren't the one doing the filtering, it's the proxy, but that's just playing with the semantics.

[Agam Banga's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43935067/344286) does *exactly* what you stated you want:

> how would I just show the names of those sports, filtering out the id and types?

Here's a full example that you can literally copy, paste, and run, and it will print out all the sports that matchbook supports:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('https://api.matchbook.com/edge/rest/lookups/sports')                                                                                                              
names = [_['name'] for _ in r.json()['sports']]                                                                                                                                     

for name in names:                                                                                                                                                                  
    print('Sport Name:', name)
```

I ran it, and here's what it output:

```
Sport Name: Australian Rules
Sport Name: Auto Racing
Sport Name: Baseball
Sport Name: Basketball
Sport Name: Boxing
Sport Name: Cricket
Sport Name: Current Events
Sport Name: Cycling
Sport Name: Darts
Sport Name: Gaelic Football
Sport Name: Golf
Sport Name: Greyhound Racing
Sport Name: Horse Racing
Sport Name: Horse Racing (Ante Post)
Sport Name: Horse Racing Beta
Sport Name: Hurling
Sport Name: Ice Hockey
Sport Name: MMA
Sport Name: NCAA Basketball
Sport Name: NCAA Football
```